# Kotlin sending an instance of sealed class as function parameter

Tags: java, kotlin

I have a sealed class which I'd like to send instances of it to another function as an argument. The function should then compare a local instance of sealed class with its argument. How can I achieve this?

```
sealed class MyState {
    data class State1(val someString: String): MyState()
    object State2: MyState()
    object State3: MyState()
}
```

The function

```
fun myFunction(conditionStateClass: Class<MyState>): Boolean {
    val newState1 = MyState.State1("foo")
    val newState2 = MyState.State2
    return newState::class.java == conditionState || newState2::class.java == conditionState // Not possible
}
```

And I'd like to call the function

```
myFunction(MyState.State1::class.java)
```

I know this is wrong. How can I achieve a similar thing?

Comment: So you want to be able to do `myFunction(MyState.State1)` *and also* `myFunction(MyState.State1("foo"))`, or just the first one? In other words, is `myFunction` checking which state, or is it also checking `someString`?

Comment: No. I want to send a class of MyState to myFunction to compare the classes. 
I think I should be using something with KClass

Comment: Can you use inline generics? `inline <reified T : MyState> myFunction<T>() { val newState1 = ...; return newState1 is T ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `kotlin.reflect.KClass` instead of `java.lang.Class` as you are writing Kotlin, and you should use [`isInstance`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/is-instance.html) to check if something is an instance of a given `KClass`.

```
fun myFunction(conditionStateClass: KClass<out MyState>): Boolean {
    val newState1 = MyState.State1("foo")
    val newState2 = MyState.State2
    return conditionStateClass.isInstance(newState1) || conditionStateClass.isInstance(newState2)
}

// Usage:
myFunction(MyState.State1::class)
```

Alternatively, use an inline function with a `reified` type parameter:

```
inline fun <reified T: MyState> myFunction(): Boolean {
    val newState1 = MyState.State1("foo")
    val newState2 = MyState.State2
    return newState1 is T || newState2 is T
}

// Usage:
myFunction<MyState.State1>()
```

Though this isn't always possible, if `myFunction` uses private members.